# Not able to upgrade to 13.10

Tags: upgrade

My system not showing the upgrade button in the software updater window.h\How can I upgrade to newer version?

Comment: the answer below should help you, but can you also update your question to indicate what version you are upgrading *from*? (in case you don't know, you can only upgrade to 13.10 from 13.04 - if you are using an earlier version, you may want post a separate question for advice on that) - and welcome to AskUbuntu!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open *Update Manager*
2. Go to *Settings* button at the bottom left.
3. Open tab at the botton which says "Notify me of a new version of ubuntu"
4. select the option that says "All new versions."

You can switch it back to only LTS versions if you find you prefer the stability to new features.